# Getting more information on ELF file

Tags: linux, elf

I started to explore and read about the ELF file in Linux and I don't understand how can I get more information about the headers of the file. Did someone has a code or something that can print what I need it will make this subject more clear!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe readelf linux utility could be of some help? For example, try

```
readelf -h -l -S <path_to_your_elf_file_here>
```

Here's a sample manual page for this utility: https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/binutils-2.12/html_chapter/binutils_14.html